# Linux HASP implementation C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hasp

Trying to implement hasp protection in my Unity project,
I put dlls file in Plugins folder it include:
hasp_net_standard.dll
libapidsp_linux_x86_64.so
libhasp_linux_x86_64_xxxxx.a
libhasp_linux_x86_64_xxxxx.so
when i run my application this code started

```
public void Init()
        {
            try
            {
                string libPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Plugins", "libhasp_linux_x86_64_27745.so");
                Debug.Log(libPath);
                _hasp = new Hasp();
                _hasp.SetLibPath(libPath);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogError(e);
            }
        }
```

And after init i try to verify key by doing this

```
 public bool VerifyKey()
        {
            try
            {
            var status = _hasp.Login(vendorCode);
            Debug.Log("Verification is sucseed with status: " + status);

            if (status == HaspStatus.StatusOk)
            {
                Debug.Log("Verification is sucseed with status: " + status);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Verification is failed with status: " + status);
                return false;
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log(e.Message);
            }      
        }
```

And i get in Unity console this message
"Verification is failed with status: NoApiDylib"
what should i include in my project to fix it?

Comment: are they designed for unity use?

Comment: Yep, it was use for unity project but in Android platform where everithing works fine

Comment: then its probably missing some libraries that android has by default - you would need to do some form of dependancy check

Comment: But the same error happends in Unity editor(which install in windows machine) and in linux build i can find the same error in logs, do u know have to perform the dependancy check in arch linux or were i can find that information?

Comment: not overly an android person so, no.  But Im guessing something called NoApiDylib ....

Comment: I think i solve this issue, I just open some dll`s file with notepad++ to see what inside, idk why, but find that NoApiDylib is error that appear when vendor code is not valid for API with generated librares wich u get from generate in tales web site, probably custumer give me the wrong vendor code so i will update this post toworrow if it helps, thx for ur time

Comment: gotta love crappy error messages - why cant it just say like "invalid key" or "invalid token" or the like

Answer (score 0):

So, the error NoApiDylib means that dlls and vendor code is not suit each other or dlls is in wrong place. Dll libhasp_linux_x86_64_xxxxx.so need to be in the same folder in which *.x86_64 file to work properly and a vendor code and feature id must fit the lib, hope it will help someone)